# updating parent table counter on sub table change

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table in my database to keep track of my website categories

first on is cat_parents

```
`parent_id` `parent_name`   `counter`
 '   1    '  ' web design'  '   1    '
```

second one is cat_subs

```
 `sub_id`  `parent_id` `sub_name`   `counter`
  ' 1   '   '   1    '  '  php  '   '   1   '
  ' 2   '   '   1    '  '  css  '   '   1   '
  ' 3   '   '   1    '  '  xml  '   '   1   '
```

and third is cat_articles

```
 `article_id`  `sub_id`  
 '  2       '  '  2  '
 '  2       '  '  3  '
 '  3       '  '  1  '
```

and there is a article table which keeps articles information like title, text and id
it goes something like :
   web design (parent_cat) >php (sub_cat) > oop programing (article_name)

now i want to be able to increase and decrease counter in `cat_parents` and `cat_subs` by each article that i delete or add in the `cat_articles` table

right now i do something like (i just wrote this and it's not my original code so ignore the syntax errors )

```
public function add_article_to_category($article_id , $sub_id ){
$sql = " select `parent_id` from `cat_subs` where `id` = '$sub_id' " ;
$parent_id  = $db->query($sql);

$sql = "update `cat_parents` set `counter` = counter + 1 where `parent_id` = $parent_id ";
$db->query($sql);


$sql = "update `cat_subs` set `counter` = counter + 1 where `sub_id` = $sub_id ";
$db->query($sql);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `cat_articles` ( `sub_id` , `article_id` ) values ('$sub_id' , '$article_id')";
$db->query($sql);
}
```

as you can see i have to run 3 different queries  and it get worst on deleting cus all i have to do is to pass the article id to the  function

```
function delete_from_category($article_id){
$sql = "delete from `cat_articles` where `article_id` = '$article_id' " ; 
}
```

i dont even need sub id in here  (and i dont want to pass the sub_id to the query in here cuz each article can b in many different sub_categorys and i first i have to get all of them and it seems like lots of work 
 )

is there any easier way to to this ?

i know it's not right and looks stupid ! but something like this :

```
function delete_from_category($article_id){

    $sql = "delete from `cat_articles` where `article_id` = '$article_id' and select 

   `sub_id`from this line and  foreachDelete  {

    update `sub_cats` set `counter` = counter-1 where `sub_id` =  $sub_idFromAboveLine and select `parent_id` 

    and( update `parent_cats` set `counter` = counter-1 where `parent_id` =  $parent_idFromAboveLine ) ))" ; 
}
```

---

ok  i'm going to do t with trigger

here is my code is it right?

```
 DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE TRIGGER decrease_counter AFTER DELETE ON cat_article
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE cat_subs SET counter= counter-1 WHERE cat_subs.sub_id = cat_article.sub_id ; 
END 
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

should i write seperate triger for cat_parents too or i can use this one? like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER decrease_counter AFTER DELETE ON cat_article
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
 UPDATE cat_subs SET counter= counter-1 WHERE cat_subs.sub_id = cat_article.sub_id ;
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
 UPDATE cat_parents SET counter= counter-1 WHERE cat_subs.parent_id=cat_parents.parent_id ;
 END
 END 
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: In regards to database normalization, you really shouldn't be storing the count of related tables in a separate table.  Better would be to run a count query to get that value.

Comment: @benjam: normally a good idea, but if this was for a "huge" discussion board, counting articles on every view would be massive query overhead. All comes down to just how 'big' this particular system will become.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be doing this using a transaction. You've got 3+ queries that each mutually depend on each other. If one fails, then all of them should fail. Right now, if your 'insert' fails but the updates succeed, you'll end up with an incorrect article count.

beyond that, you can achieve this functionality using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). It would catch any inserts/deletes on the cat_articles table, and would automatically run the appropriate updates on cat_parents and cat_subs. Even though 3 queries would still be executed, your code would only issue the one "insert" or "delete" query - the DBMS will take care of the rest for you in the background.

Comment: THANX I'VE UPDATE MY CODE THERE IS A QUESTION ABOUT TRIGGER AT THE END OF MY POST PLEAS TAKE LOOK AT IT

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way to store categories, data will become redundant very quickly.

Look at this article on the Nested Set Model http://www.planetkodiak.com/code/hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

The nested set model is basically like this

```
Root lft = 1 rgt = 8
    Sub1 = left = 2 rgt = 5
        SubSub1 = left = 3 rgt = 4
    Sub2 = left = 6 rgt = 7
```

Everything between 1 and 8 is a child of the Root and everything between 2 and 5 is a child of Sub1 and so on